# How to get length of array in template syntax

Tags: angular

I am trying to evaluate the below in template syntax which is an array:

```
FAIL 
{{ cols.length }}
```

I get the below error.

```
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

But I do iterate so I know that portion works:

```
      SUCCESS
     <th *ngFor="let h of cols"> 
        {{h}}
      </th>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use

```
{{ cols?.length }}
```

Or

```
<div *ngIf="cols">{{ cols.length }}</div>
```

If you want to print 0 for empty array, use

```
{{ cols?.length || '0' }}
```

Reason: `cols` is not initiated when Angular2 load the template. And we want to wait until it's ready to access its members.

Comment: if empty then how to print zero

Comment: I have student array it contains 3 student obj but every time it print 1 only.

Answer (score 4):

Try defining the cols variable as an object list on `.ts` archive
`cols: object[]`;

If you want to print 0 for an empty array use the ternary operator:

```
{{ cols ? cols.length : '0' }}
```