# how do i get the length of an array that is inside an object in angular from the html or ts?

Tags: html, angular

what i trying to get from the console:

https://i.ibb.co/LtcCZfY/Untitled.png

this what i try to do in the html but no luck

```
  <div class="cell" *ngFor="let s of allShips">
  <h3>{{s.name}}</h3>

  <span>{{s.passenger.length}}</span>
```

allShip.ts

```
  allShips: Ship[];

  constructor(private shipService: ShipService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shipService.getAllShips().subscribe(
      (ships)=>{
        this.allShips = ships;
        console.log(ships);
      // console.log(ships['passenger[0]'].length);

      },
      (err)=>{
        alert(err); 
      }
    )
  }
```

allShips.html

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="cell" *ngFor="let s of allShips">
  <h3>{{s.name}}</h3>

  <span>{{s.passenger.name}}</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Are you able to display the name?

Comment: on the length i get :Unresolved variable length

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu no nothing showd up no even an error in the console

Comment: This probably happens because allShips get assigned asynchronusly, try optional chaining, like this s?.name / s?.passenger?.length. Btw, this is just an assumption, we can not solve the error unless we see all the details and a full sample.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu  i updated the question, hope now you could help me

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048734/how-to-get-length-of-array-in-template-syntax

Comment: @FotisPapadamis thanks but that not what am looking for because its not an array inside an object

Comment: @wedew2 did you implement that logic in your situation?

Comment: yes it not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <div class="grid" *ngIf="allShips | async as ships">
            <div class="cell" *ngFor="let s of ships">
              <h3>{{s.name}}</h3>
              <span>{{s.passenger.name}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your for loop with a container to make sure allShips is initialized by the time ngFor runs:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allShips">
 <div class="cell" *ngFor="let s of allShips">
   <h3>{{s.name}}</h3>
   <span>{{s.passenger.length}}</span>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```